# Return all parents with only exactly one child in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I want to write a query that returns only the parents with exactly one child.  I have this so far...

```
parents = Parent.all
parents = parents.reject {|parent| parent.children.count > 1}
```

This works but the only problem I'm running into is that the returned data type is an Array, not an ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Parent data type.  I am using a gem (Kaminari pagination gem) that is running into an error because it expects an Active Record relation datatype as opposed to an array.

Does anyone know how I can return all parents with only one child using ActiveRecord rather than doing this with ruby code?

```
parents = Parent.joins(:children).code_here_to_query_for_parents_with_only_one_child?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Parent.joins(:children).group('parents.id').having('count("children.parent_id") = 1')
```

Edit: Hmmm it looks like if I chain any "WHERE" SQL commands it breaks the query =/

Edit2:  Here's what I ended up doing:

```
parents = Parent.all #I have a bunch of chained WHERE clauses if parameters are present above
parents = parents.joins(:children).where("parents.id IN (?)",Parent.joins(:children).group("parents.id").having('count("children.parent_id") = 1'))  if params[:single_child].present?
```